# What causes an HTTP 405 “invalid method (HTTP verb)” error when POSTing a form (using CPSHOST.DLL) on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I'm in the process of migrating a series of classic ASP web pages from a Windows 2000 server to a Windows 2008 R2 server.  One of the pages uses CPSHOST.DLL (in the Scripts folder) to upload a file to the server.

The page in question uses a POST method on the form, but consistently returns a "Method Not Allowed" response when the page runs.  I have changed the method from lowercase to uppercase, and I have configured the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions to allow the cpshost.dll to run.

The page in question prompts the userid for a file format type (3 possible options are available), and a file name.  The form header is as follows:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://dcnb/scripts/cpshost.dll?PUBLISH?http://dcnb/scripts/dcn_cnam_repost.asp?user_id=jsommer&telco_code=GRGS" id=image_upload name=image_upload >
```

I tried changing the follwup .asp routine, in case it was throwing the error, but it made no difference (i.e., I changed the code to call a different web page than the repost.asp page, but to no avail.

The detailed error informaiton tells me the following:

Module: StaticFileModule, Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler, Handler: StaticFile, and Errorcode: 0x800700001.

The Requested URL is:

```
http://dcnb/scripts/cpshost.dll?PUBLISH?http://dcnb/scripts/dcn_cnam_repost.asp?user_id=jsommer&telco_code=GRGS
```

The physical path is listed as c:\inetpub\wwwroot\dcn\scripts\cpshost.dll, which is correct.  The Logon Method and Logon User are both Anonymous.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I have looked around for pure ASP solutions for uploading files (to eliminate the use of cpshost.dll), but have yet to find one that works in the IIS 7 environment.  If anyone has any suggestions there, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try running Process Monitor when you request the page. Please confirm if the process is able access to cpshost.dll. If everything looks good, you can try running Failed Request Tracing to get some good information on what stage the request fails.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this.  I actually wound up scrapping the idea of using the cpshost.dll, and am in the process of revising the original .asp page with an asp.net version.  The new version uses the file upload object, and seems to work quite well.  I'm having a different problem with the new asp.net routine, but I'll post a separate question on it.  Thanks again!